# Creating a submenu for every parent page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

What I have is a very deep menu structure in Wordpress, 5 levels deep in some pages. What I need is a menu for every parent above the current page. So for example if I am here:

*Main / Sub / SubSub / SubSubSub* I want to see, above each other:

- Menu for all main items
- Menu for all items in Sub
- Menu for all items in SubSub, including SubSubSub

I am using the wp_list_pages function like this:

```
<?php
  if ( $post->post_parent ) {

$args = array(
  'child_of'    => $post->ID,
  'depth'       => 1,
  'sort_column' => 'post_date',
  'sort_order'  => 'DESC',
  'title_li'    => ''
);
echo '<nav id="subnav"><ul>';
  wp_list_pages( $args );
echo '</ul></nav>';

} ?>
```

But I cannot tell if I am at lvl 2 or below. I found the ancestor menu (always shown) with this bit:

```
'child_of' => get_post_top_ancestor_id()
```

But I cannot get it to list one menu for every other parent that is not the topmost ancestor. I tried modifying this code here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/list-wordpress-custom-menus-active-parent-levels-children-as-separate-menu

and looping through all parents like here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-and-display-parent-pages-of-a-menu

Main problem is I am not much of a PHP programmer so creating my own functions is not really an option. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This looks a bit more promising, it spits out every parent above it, trying to change the plain title to a full blown menu... Still, help is appreciated by the strugglers.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-parent-pages

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, I still nee to loop through $howdeep > 2 and find the correct level to show... If someone knows how to do it...

```
<?php

$id = 0;
$thispost = get_post($id);
$howdeep = 1;
$parentID = $thispost->post_parent;
while( $parentID != 0 ) {
$parent = get_post($parentID);
$howdeep++;
$parentID = $parent->post_parent;
}

if ( $howdeep == 2 ) {

$args = array(
    'child_of'      => $post->ID,
    'depth'         => 1,
    'sort_column'   => 'post_date',
    'sort_order'    => 'DESC',
    'title_li'      => ''
);
echo '<nav id="subsubnav"><ul>';
    wp_list_pages( $args );
echo '</ul></nav>';

} else if ( $howdeep == 3 ) {

$args = array(
    'child_of'      => $post->post_parent,
    'depth'         => 1,
    'sort_column'   => 'post_date',
    'sort_order'    => 'DESC',
    'title_li'      => ''
);
echo '<nav id="subsubnav"><ul>';
    wp_list_pages( $args );
echo '</ul></nav>';

} ?>
```